# Javascript, NodeJS: Call Asychronous Methods in a Loop & Return Result

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

Is there a way that i could call a Async Method in a loop, put all the results in a array & return the results in the end.

Pseudo Code of what i want to do:

```
methodThatRunsAsync(callback){
  once completes, invoke callback;
}
```

> anotherMethod (){
>      var result = [];
>      for(i=1; i=10; i++){
>
> ```
>  methodThatRunsAsync(function(resp){
>     result.push(resp);
>  });
>
> return result;    }
> ```
>
> }

But the value of result is always the default value. How can i trap the results of the async block in a sync block and return the same to the caller.

Looking into Promise framework, but finding it a bit tough to get my head around it. If anyone can please help me understand how to achieve this, psuedo code too would be great.

Comment: https://github.com/caolan/async - Has everything you need.

Comment: Thank You...!! Trying not to use the library, any easy way I could write my own module for this. What would be the design pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't return the result, as the calls as asynchronous. Use a callback for that function too, and call it when the last result is added:

```
function anotherMethod (callback) {
  var result = [];
  var count = 10;
  for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    methodThatRunsAsync(function(resp){
      result.push(resp);
      if (result.length == count) {
        callback(result);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Note that I changed the loop. The loop that you had would not do any iterations at all.

Comment: Wow.. that was really simple, thanks a ton. But are there any drawbacks in using this method.

Comment: @ErrolDsilva: A limitation is that it relies on all calls resulting in a callback. If the asynchronous method could fail or take too long, you might want to add a timeout and call the callback with the results that you got.